# How can I parse a string with a date calculation like now + 1 days into a date object?

Tags: javascript, date, cucumber, momentjs, cucumberjs

I'm currently using Cucumber to define our test cases in string based feature files. The integration tests will run against a wiremock stub which has date calculations like: "{{now offset='+15 minutes'}}"

I want to validate that the date and time I'm getting from the wiremock stub are displayed correctly, that the date and time are correct and that the table is ordered properly based on that date and time.

We currently have our own implementation to get now +/- X days. That uses some regex and only supports days. I can expand that code and add minutes to that but I would much rather use a library or a standardized piece of code that can parse all date calculations. I haven't been able to find it and would love some suggestions on how to solve this.

To give you an idea of what I'm working with at the moment:

```
function stringReplaceNow(string) {
  var regex = /<now:([A-Z-]+):?((\+|-)([0-9]+))?>/gi;

  return string.replace(regex, function (match, format, shouldModify, modification, modAmount) {
    if (modification === '+') {
      return moment().add(modAmount, 'days').format(format);
    } else if (modification === '-') {
      return moment().subtract(modAmount, 'days').format(format);
    }
    return moment().format(format);
  });
}
```

In our cucumber tests it gets used like this, it will get the current date and subtract the days accordingly:

```
| Name             | Datetime            | State      |
| Johnson          | <now:DD-MM-YYYY:-2> | Processing |
| Minter           | <now:DD-MM-YYYY:-3> | Processing |
| Brown            | <now:DD-MM-YYYY:-5> | Done       |
```

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: So where else am I going to find an answer to my question? I'm looking for a good solution to my problem, I'm not asking you to recommend a whole infrastructure on which you can have thousands of opinions.

Comment: @Andreas I edited the question, it doens't ask for a library anymore but it doesn't change the problem I have.

Comment: _"but I would much rather use a library or a standardized piece of code that can parse all date calculations"_ o.O

Comment: I still see no question or problem. Explain what your problem is with implementing this on your own

Comment: That I don't think it's a good practice to reinvent the wheel, especially when you think that someone else might have figured this out already and might have put it in a library. 

The answer I got below has put me in a different direction than I was initially thinking and that's exactly what I expect from a good answer on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standards for date calculations so I doubt you'll find a library for it. However you can use parts of the existing standards so simplify your custom date calculations.

In this instance, rather then developing your own format consider using the ISO-8601 duration format. You can then use existing libraries to parse the duration format and add it to the current time.

Examples:

```
"PT20.345S" -- parses as "20.345 seconds"
"PT15M"     -- parses as "15 minutes" (where a minute is 60 seconds)
"PT10H"     -- parses as "10 hours" (where an hour is 3600 seconds)
"P2D"       -- parses as "2 days" (where a day is 24 hours or 86400 seconds)
"P2DT3H4M"  -- parses as "2 days, 3 hours and 4 minutes"
"PT-6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and +3 minutes"
"-PT6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and -3 minutes"
"-PT-6H+3M"  -- parses as "+6 hours and -3 minutes"
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna try that right now and let you know. Seems like a good solution. I think I will still use <now:format:duration> as a format so I can reuse some of the old code.

Comment: The momentjs library has a function to parse an ISO string duration into a Duration. You can then do .add(Duration) on an existing moment. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Answer (score -2):

Try using [DayJs](https://day.js.org/). Its is light weight and having more features than momentjs.

Comment: I see the parse function that can read a string and convert it to a date but it doesn't include a manipulation in a string. It will only parse a date and then you can do .add() on that date to manipulate it. The problem is that I can't to .add() in a cucumber file so I would have to parse the manipulation myself.